# how to disable horizontal scrollbar into pivot control WP7.?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have Image and I am zooming this image as well Draging this image and move around this canvas,

so the canvas is inside the Pivot Control and once I am trying to move from Left to Right so it will goes to the next Pivot Item so I want to stop this horizontal scrollbar into this PivotItem.?

NOTE:
I had tried with Touch.FrameReported but is not worth in my case.

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Lockable Pivot control from the [Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) :-

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-LockablePivot-in-depth

Comment: thanks alot, but I want to lock only PivotItem it is Lock whole the Pivot Cotrol so user can't see any other menu items and that would be the problem. can you give me idea on this.once again thanks for you quick reply.:)

Comment: If you unlock the Pivot control then you can gain access to the other PivotItems.

Comment: yes but it will crash the application I wanted once my PivotItem has been locked still I have to go another PivotItem and so and so then the Only One PivotItem I have to locked.